# Ways to set debconf to run non-interactively?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, debian

There seams to be two ways to set debconf to run non-interactively:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```

What is the difference of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect these to have the same effect except in corner cases.

For instance, the environment variable can be lost if a process specifically unsets it, or launches a child process after clearing all environment variables. On the other hand, the debconf setting doesn't depend on shell environments being preserved, so it's less fragile.